# How to add marker to a specific location in Google Maps in Android Studio?

Tags: android, location, marker

I have created a button which takes the user to a specific location on Google Maps. Here is the snippet:

```
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", latitude, longitude);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
                        context.startActivity(intent);
```

However, the Map merely zooms to the particular location without adding a marker to the co-ordinates I have put. Can someone please help me?

Thank You.

Comment: have you try like this uri  http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=500x500&location=" + myLatitude  + "," + myLongitude + "&fov=90&heading=235&pitch=10&sensor=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me (the 'hellothere' is a label you can replace or remove):

```
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:0,0?q=%f,%f(hellothere)",latitude,longitude);
```

UPDATE:  the geo: parameter can be 0,0 when supplying a location query.

(When testing you may want to close the Map app each test particularly if not moving the marker.)

Comment: Thanks! The marker is now visible. However I couldn't see the "hello there" label you mentioned in the parentheses in your solution.

Comment: Just to be clear -  there is no space in 'hellothere' so it didn't need urlencoding - or simply do 'hello+there'.